# Making three vertices symmetric without moving middle vertex

Tags: mesh, workflow

I'm making a shoe. It should have parts that are symmetric, and parts that are not symmetric so mirror modifier is not a good solution. I would like to make three vertices connected with 2 edges exactly symmetric with center of symmetry in the middle vertex. That middle vertex is exactly where it's supposed to be, and I want it to remain in the exact place.

What workflow could I use to make one of the vertices to be exact mirror of the second one?

[image: Three verticies]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use snap to symmetry feature.

Select vertexes that you want to move in mirrored position. Then in menu choose Mesh -> Snap to Symmetry.

Then you need to adjust threshold using Adjust last operation (<kbd>F9</kbd> or panel in bottom right corner)

Optionally, you can edit factor, to define what vertexes you want to move.

[image]

Then you can use X-mirror option to keep this vertexes in sync. This setting is located in 3 places:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Works perfectly! Great thanks!